# Identified Laravel Deserialization Remote Code Execution (CVE-2021-3129) in non-Laravel Application: How to Mitigate?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, security

I discovered a vulnerability related to Laravel's Deserialization Remote Code Execution (CVE-2021-3129) within my web application. Surprisingly, my application does not utilize Laravel directly. However, the vulnerability seems to exist. How should I proceed to address and mitigate this issue in a non-Laravel application?

Steps Taken:

Reviewed the codebase thoroughly but found no direct usage of Laravel.
Examined third-party dependencies, yet unsure if any might include Laravel components.
Unsure how to effectively resolve this vulnerability without direct Laravel usage.
Seeking advice on:

Possible sources or hidden dependencies that might introduce Laravel components.
Best practices to identify and eliminate this vulnerability in a non-Laravel application context.
Recommendations for security measures or tools specialized in detecting CVE-2021-3129 in indirect dependencies.
Any guidance or insights on handling this scenario would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You say you don't use Laravel directly, but do you use it indirectly? If so, how?

Comment: no , actually i am not using any laravel

Comment: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-3129: _"Ignition before 2.5.2, as used in Laravel and other products, allows unauthenticated remote attackers to execute arbitrary code because of insecure usage of file_get_contents() and file_put_contents(). This is exploitable on sites using debug mode with Laravel before 8.4.2."_ - so the actual problem appears to be with `Ignition`, and Laravel is only affected because it uses that library/component.

Comment: @CBore but i am not using laravel so is it possible that might be i have Igntiontion in my code

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you're using Composer, check your composer.lock to see if Ignition is listed

Comment: The release page for Ignition state that the issue was fixed in version [1.6.15](https://github.com/facade/ignition/releases/tag/1.6.15). You could make sure to update your dependencies and validate if you are still using this version.

Comment: i checked the entire project folder no composer.lock file is found

Comment: we are using core PHP framework , not using any composer-based library

Comment: how did you find this vulnerability?

Comment: one of my customers did audit on my web app and they provided us the report with the above vulnerability